# Reference on a theorem of algebraic geometry

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

In the book GTM 52 by R.Hartshone, there is a theorem as following :

> Every variety of dimension $r$ is birational to a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{r+1}$

Could you please tell me, who is the author of this theorem ?

I have read somewhere that birational equivalence was considered in Italian school, so could you please show me what exactly they did found relating to classification of variety(w.r.t birational equivalence).

Thank!

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4324/examples-of-birational-equivalence-of-a-variety-and-a-hypersurface, which is quite related.

Answer (score 7):

That theorem is probably folkloric, in that there is no name attached to it.

The proof is very simple (let me work over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero) If $K(X)$ is the field of rational functions on a variety $X$ of dimension $r$, then the trascendence degree of $K(X)$ over $k$ is $r$ and there are functions $x_1,\dots,x_r\in K(X)$ algebraically independent over $k$ such that the extension $K(X)\supset k(x_1,\dots,x_r)$ is finite and separable. It is therefore *simple*, so there exists an $x_{r+1}\in K(X)$ such that $K(X)=k(x_1,\dots,x_{r+1})$. Moreover, since the extension is finite, there is a polynomial $f$ such that $f(x_1,\dots,x_{r+1})=0$.

Now $f$ defines a hypersurface in the affine space $\mathbb A^{r+1}$, and its projective closure is a hypersurface in $\mathbb P^{r+1}$. It is easy to see that the field of rational functions on the latter is isomorphic to $K(X)$.

Comment: Could you please explain for me why the field of rational function of the latter is isomorphic to $K(X)$ ?